# Printf printing only a single line

Tags: bash, shell, quoting, printf

I'm trying to get the output of `env` in a shell variable and print it.

```
#!/bin/sh
ENV_BEFORE=$(env)
printf $ENV_BEFORE
```

As a result a single variable from the `env` output gets printed.

When using `echo` instead of `printf` all the output is printed, however without the newlines.

*What am I missing here?*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that you're not quoting the `$ENV` variable. As explained in `man bash`:

> Enclosing characters in double quotes preserves the  literal  value
>   of all  characters  within the quotes, with the exception of $, `,
>   \, and,    when history expansion is enabled, !.  The characters $ 
>   and  `  retain    their  special meaning within double quotes.  **The
>   backslash retains its    special meaning only when followed by one of
>   the following  characters:    $,  `,  ", \, or** .

So, enclosing a sequence like `\n` in double quotes preserves its meaning. This is why, when not quoted, `\n` is just a normal `n`:

```
$ printf \n
n$
```

While, when quoted:

```
$ printf "\n"

$
```

An unquoted variable in bash invokes the split+glob operator. This means that the variable is split on whitespace (or whatever the special variable `$IFS` has been set to) and each resulting word is used as a glob (it will expand to match any matching file names). Your problem is with the "split" part of this.

To illustrate, let's take a simpler multiline variable:

```
$ var=$(printf "foo\nbar\n")
```

Now, using the shell's `set -x` debug feature, you can see exactly what's going on:

```
$ echo $var
+ echo foo bar
foo bar

$ echo "$var"
+ echo 'foo
bar'
foo
bar
```

As you can see above, `echo $var` (unquoted) subjects `$var` to split+glob so it results in two separate strings, `foo` and `bar`. The newline was eaten by th split+glob. When the variable was quoted, it wasn't subjected to split+glob, the newline was kept and, because it is quoted, is also interpreted correctly ad printed out.

The next problem is that `printf` is not like `echo`. It doesn't just print anything you give it, it expects a format string. For example `printf "color:%s" "green"` will print `color:green` because the `%s` will be replaced with `green`.

It also ignores any input that can't fit into the format string it was given. So, if you run `printf foo bar`, `printf` will treat `foo` as its format string and `bar` as the variable it is supposed to format with it. Since there is no `%s` or equivalent to be replaced by `bar`, `bar` is ignored and `foo` alone is printed:

```
$ printf $var
+ printf foo bar
foo
```

That's what happened when you ran `printf $ENV_BEFORE`. Because the variable wasn't quoted, the split glob effectively replaced newlines with spaces, and `printf` only printed the first "word" it saw.

To do it correctly, use format strings, and always quote your variables:

```
printf '%s\n' "$ENV_BEFORE"
```

Answer (score 5):

`printf` (unlike `echo`) does not print newline by default, you have to explicitly tell it:

```
printf "${ENV_BEFORE}\n"
```

Or better:

```
printf '%s\n' "$ENV_BEFORE"
```

---

After [@don_crissti](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269662/printf-printing-only-a-single-line/269663?noredirect=1#comment467475_269663) rightly pointed out in the comment and after i have read the question again, i think your case is different from above.

In your case, the problem is that you have not quoted the variable `$ENV_BEFORE`.

Here are the behaviors of `printf` and `echo` if you don't quote a variable:

- `printf`:

  1. Without quote and any format specifier it will only print the first word
  2. With quote and without any format specifier, it would consider anything in the expansion  having `%` as format specifier and could choke
  3. Without quote and with a format specifier, it will subject to word splitting and pathname expansion, hence would lead to unexpected result as any value of `IFS` would become a space in the output
  4. With quote and format specifier, you would get desired result i.e. no word splitting and pathname expansion will be performed on the expansion.
- `echo`:

  1. Without quote the variable expansion will subject to word splitting and pathname expansion, hence you would not get the desired output
  2. With `quote` the variable expansion will not subject to word splitting and pathname expansion and hence you would get the desired output

Comment: It works with what you suggested, thanks. However I can't understand the syntax that made it happen. Because of the added `\n` in `'%s\n'`all the newlines in `ENV_BEFORE` will be taken into account?

Comment: @Alan Check my edits please..